# Avoid jagged edges after size change

Tags: gimp, png, gif

I have been given a PNG image of a simple logo and with a transparent background. Size needs to be reduced but the smaller image has jagged edges. I have tried to keep the resolution unchanged, and I even tried to lower the resolution but without result. In this case it may be quicker to create the logo again in the correct size but I would really appreciate a chance to learn why this happens and how to avoid it.

Please note that the logos contain white text and therefore do not display well below.

Original image:

> [image: Original image]

Transformed image:

> [image: Transformed image]

Answer (score 6):

This has little to do with size change. Your small image is a GIF, and in a GIF there is no partial opacity/transparency: it’s all or nothing, so this doesn’t allow the partially transparent pixels that make smooth edges (a technique known as anti-aliasing). Below, your big image scaled down in Gimp (top) and the scaled image you posted (bottom). The top image has partially transparent pixels:

[image]

To keep the anti-aliasing, save your image in a format that support partial transparency (typically, PNG, like your source image).

> [image]

(white-on-bright-yellow image above...)

If the GIF format is required (but why would it in 2018?), before exporting to GIF you can use [*Layer → Transparency → Semi-flatten*](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-semiflatten.html) to create anti-aliasing edge pixels **over a predetermined color**. But of course the picture can only be shown over a background of that color, which somehow defeats the purpose of the transparent background.

PS: If you make the image color-indexed explicitly in Gimp (*Image → Mode → Indexed*), then Gimp will show you the layers with the GIF “binary” opacity. If you are in full RGB mode, this only appears when the picture is exported to GIF.